# How to exclude schema from hibernate auto ddl

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on spring boot application that needs to connect with PostgresSql data base to read some records from **TaskOne** table in schema **TaskReads** and which writes some data to **TaskTwo** table in schema **TaskWrites**, so I have enabled `hibernate.auto.ddl` to create `schemas` and `tables` if not exists and it's working.

**Problem**

Now the problem is my since my application is just reading data from **TaskOne** table in **TaskReads** schema I don't wanna perform any ddl commands even if schema and table are not existing.

And since my application is inserting records in to **TaskTwo** table in **TaskWrites** schema I'm responsible to create schema and table if not exists.

**TaskTwo** entity which only reads data

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TaskOne", schema = "TaskReads")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Subselect(value = "")
@Immutable
public class TaskOneEntity {

@Column(name = "task_id")
@Id
private Long taskId;

 }
```

**TaskTwo** entity writes data into table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TaskTwo", schema = "TaskWrites")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class TaskTwoEntity {


@Column(name = "task_id")
@Id
private long taskId;

 }
```

So by using `@Subselect` annotation I achieved not creating table even it is not existing, but still it is creating schema if schema is not existing in database.

**How can I achieve excluding schema in auto ddl ?**

Comment: Did you consider using a databse migration tool? Spring [supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool) two migration tools: [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) and [Flywaydb](https://flywaydb.org/).

Comment: If you do not want to create any table or schema, just mention auto ddl as update or donot mention it at all.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot achieve that directly, since `hibernate.auto.ddl` is enabled whole database level  and not `schema` level

**@Subselect(value = "")** make the entity read-only and avoids creating table.

**@Table(name = "TaskOne")** In table annotation remove the `schema` part so that it will check in the default schema (which is public in postgresql) and not going to do anything still if table and schema not exists